# Fingerprint check fails - Schengen

Tags: schengen

Short but necessary background: I live in the UK (resident), a nonEU citizen. I lived/worked in the EU in the past. On multiple occasions, my fingerprints were checked at the border in the past with no problems. In fact, at the UK border, this is regular - never had an issue, always went through.

I got a new Schengen visa last year (long tourist visa,>1 year with 90 days stay, etc). Since then, on two trips out of only three trips I made, border police wanted to check my fingerprints and every time they were not happy, making me try several times - eventually letting me (without a positive match). Now since I do not have a regular fingerprint problem, I think this is an issue about the last biometrics I gave - maybe they didn't take it properly now causing issues.

I am worried about a possible escalation of this and I am not sure what implications this might have. In particular, is there any probability that they won't let me in/out or do something else?

Is there anything I can do, anyway? To complain somewhere / give fingerprints again?

I have checked other posts and have seen nothing similar, so I am a bit worried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am worried about a possible escalation of this and I am not sure what implications this might have

No implications whatsoever. Biometric checks fail all the time and the border guards would've seen hundreds of cases of this happening. The only consequence is that they'll have to spend a bit more time to cross-check your identity.

> is there any probability that they won't let me in/out or do something else?

Highly unlikely. The technology is not foolproof and at the end of the day it has to be supplemented by a human decision process. Relax and enjoy your next trip.